# How to compare locale dependent float numbers?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I need to compare a float value entered in a web form against a range. The problem is that the client computers may have various locale settings, meaning that user may use either "." or "," to separate the integer part from decimal one.

Is there a simple way to do it? As it is for an intranet and that they are only allowed to use IE, a VBScript is fine, even if I would prefer to use JavaScript.

EDIT: Let me clarify it a bit:

I cannot rely on the system locale, because, for example, a lot of our french customers use a computer with an english locale, even if they still use the comma to fill data in the web forms.
So I need a way to perform a check accross multiple locale "string to double" conversion.
I know that the raise condition is "what about numbers with 3 decimal digits", but in our environment, this kind of answer never happen, and if it happens, it will be threated as an out of range error due to the multiplication by a thousand, so it's not a real issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript use `parseFloat` on the text value to get a number.  Similarly in VBScript use `CDbl` on the text value.  Both should conform to the current locale settings enforce for the user.

Comment: Well, CDbl don't work fine. If, for example, you try to convert "3,5" using the wrong Locale, the result won't be 3, but 35 which makes comparison impossible.

Comment: @gizmo: Are you doing this client-side or server-side? I can't see why the "wrong locale" would be used client-side.

Comment: Because, for exemple, it's not because you're a french guy, writing your decimal with a comma, that the locale of your computer is well configured. We have to test if a decimal number make sens, whathever is the system locale. I know it won't work if there is 3 decimals, but that's another problem

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
  function toFloat(localFloatStr)
    var x = localFloatStr.split(/,|\./),
        x2 = x[x.length-1],
        x3 = x.join('').replace(new RegExp(x2+'$'),'.'+x2);
    return parseFloat(x3);
    //  x2 is for clarity, could be omitted:
    //=>x.join('').replace(new RegExp(x[x.length-1]+'$'),'.'+x[x.length-1])
  } 

  alert(toFloat('1,223,455.223')); //=> 1223455.223
  alert(toFloat('1.223.455,223')); //=> 1223455.223
  // your numbers ;~)
  alert(toFloat('3.123,56')); //=> 3123.56
  alert(toFloat('3,123.56')); //=> 3123.56
```

Answer (score 0):

What we do is try parsing using the culture of the user and if that doesn't work, parse it using an invariant culture.

I wouldn't know how to do it in javascript or vbscript exactly though.

Answer (score 0):

I used KooiInc's answer but change it a bit, because it didn't reckon with some cases.

```
function toFloat(strNum) {
    var full = strNum.split(/[.,]/);

    if (full.length == 1) return parseFloat(strNum);

    var back = full[full.length - 1];
    var result = full.join('').replace(new RegExp(back + '$'), '.' + back);

    return parseFloat(result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Forbid using any thousands separator.

Give the user an example: "Reals should look like this: `3123.56` or `3123,56`". Then simply change `,` to `.` and parse it.

You can always tell user that he did something wrong with a message like this:

```
"I don't understand what you mean by "**,**,**".  
Please format numbers like "3123.56."
```